# PPS (Protocol and Parameter Selection) command - Global Platform Scripting

Tags: smartcard, emv, globalplatform

I am trying to set PPS on Smartcard. The environment I am using is based on Global Platform scripting. The command description:

```
Boolean pps(Number protocol) 
Boolean pps(Number protocol, Number f, Number d)
```

> Set the physical protocol for the card. The GP scripting language
> provides support for contact smart cards through ISO7816. Other
> proprietary protocols can be supported, but depend on support by the
> environment implementing the GP scripting language. If the method
> executes successfully, then a true Boolean value is returned.
> Otherwise, if the parameters are valid, but the environment cannot
> execute the method for the smart card represented by card, then a
> false value is returned. If invalid values (i.e., values not specified
> in this specification or values not supported by the environment) for
> any of the parameters protocol, f, or d are provided, then a GPError
> object is generated with GPError.INVALID_DATA value.

> Sample:

```
// On a card with a contact interface 
this.card.pps(Card.T1, myFrequency, myDivisor); 
// returns false value if the card doesn’t support T=1 protocol
```

> **protocol**
>
> The protocol parameter will contain the desired protocol value
> corresponding to a value defined as supported in the Card Profile.
> Valid values for contact cards (via ISO7816) are:
>
> Card.T0
> Card.T1
> Card.T14
>
> If any of the above values are specified, then the f and d parameters
> are also required.  For a proprietary protocol supported by the card,
> a unique protocol value supported by the environment can be used, as
> long as it does not conflict with the values defined for the Card
> constants. The following is a default constant for representing
> non-standard protocols :
> Card.OTHER
> Refer to ISO specifications for
> ISO7816.
>
> **f** - Clock rate conversion factor
> **d** - Number Baud rate adjustment
> factor

According to GP platform description my command for baud rate 38400 looks following:

```
  this.card.reset( Card.RESET_COLD );
  this.card.pps(Card.T1, 372, 4);
```

The response I receive from PPS is false. The cold ATR is: 3B680000990200D103042201

The questions:

- GP PPS command parameters the number I am not sure if it should be 372, 4 or 10, 13 for baud rate 38400?
- The given ATR looks as it supports T0 protocol my command might need to be: this.card.pps(Card.T0, 372, 4);?
- or  I might need to do warm reset and if warm ATR supports T1 protocol then send this.card.pps(Card.T1, 372, 4);?

ATR:

- TS: 3B
- T0: 68 -> TB1, TC1, 8 historical characters
- TB1: 00 -> Vpp is not used; the programming voltage for the EEPROM is generated in the chip
- TC1: 00 -> No extra guard time
- Historical Bytes (T1-T8): 990200D103042201

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer due to lack of Javacard experience:

If I understand correctly, you want to set-up your card, so it accepts PPS. (The reader has to trigger it, so the card can only indicate capabilities.)

- Your ATR has to provide a TA1 byte to indicate its PPS support to the reader. For an external clock of 3.57 Mhz this has to be 13 if 38400 bit/s are desired maximum.
- Note, that PPS just establishes division factors to be applied to external clock. If the reader provides a different clock than 3.57 MHz, your communication rate will scale directly proportional. (For other clock ranges the high nibble of TA1 indicating Fi has to be changed, according to ISO 7816-3)
- PPS is only possible after reset.

Comment: Java Card doesn't respond to PPS, you can only use it to set historical bytes, and then only if you've got the right privileges (i.e. being the default application). So I guess you have enough understanding of Java Card for this answer. Of course, different vendors may have initialization phases that do enable you to tinker...